# C++ - Have a type be able to hold it's children

Tags: c++, linked-list, polymorphism, derived-class

I have a linked list of type Device:

```
Node<Device> list = new Node<device>(device);
```

And Device have derived classes:

[image]

And I need my list to be able to hold every derived class of Device.

How can I do it?

*Note: If I send an Aerobic_Device to the list, it just dynamically converts to Device, which loses data.*

**EDIT:**

I changed all the logic of my program to work with pointers, and now the list is: `Node<Device*>` - Which still converts everything to Device type.
Now, as many suggested, I switched it to `Node<std::unique_ptr<Device>>`, but this just introduced many many many errors.

Comment: Post content of class/struct Device/device.

Comment: Looks like you want some smart pointers.

Comment: You need a list of pointers. If this is not a homework, please use a standard container.

Comment: You can store an ID for each type, and define in Device: int getType(); to get that ID.

Comment: I _think_ that your problem is two things: 1. You need to store a pointer to `Device` in the list. 2. You will need a common interface [or use `dynamic_cast`] using virtual functions.

Comment: This question is now closed. If you have a question about storing raw pointers or unique_ptrs in a list, ask a new question. I recommend you do that, because your remarks suggest that your understanding of polymorphism in C++ is lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the list to be of type `Device*` (note the pointer).

```
Node<Device*> list;
```

Then, declare objects of derived types (`PowerDevice`, `AerobicDevice`, `PowerAerobicDevice`) and put them in the list.

This way you can leverage the power of runtime polymorphism.

Alternatively, you can (and should) use smart pointers instead of raw pointers to automatically handle the memory:

```
std::unique_ptr<Device> pDevice= std::make_unique<PowerDevice>(...);
// put into list
std::unique_ptr<Device> aDevice= std::make_unique<AerobicDevice>(...);
// put into list
std::unique_ptr<Device> paDevice= std::make_unique<PowerAerobicDevice>(...);
// put into list
```

Comment: This doesn't answer to him. What he wants is to identify which sub class is used, to cast them to retrieve the attributes. He already does what you say.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Can you read OP's code? Because I can't see that in the question.

Comment: juanchopanza: re-read the question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store your objects by value and have polymorphic behavior at the same time. You can store your objects by (preferably smart) pointer:

```
Node<std::unique_ptr<Device>> list;
```

Comment: Ok, why not just regular pointers?

Comment: @Amit Because smart pointers will do the memory management for you, and that's what you should use.

Comment: You can use regular pointer, since there is no multi inheritance.

Comment: @Amit If somebody else owns the objects, it is OK to use plain pointers. But it the list owns them, or shares the ownership, then you need a smart pointer that expresses that ownership model.